# Find and print first word with matching pattern

Tags: grep, text-processing

I have a text file in which there are two columns:

```
Name Age
```

I want to search a part of `Name` in this file and on finding the first match, I want to print the whole `Name`
Example:

```
Name                   Age
Ashok Kumar(father)    32
Deepak khan(son)      19
Nirmal khan(son)       21

I want to search for(son) and want to return Deepak khan
```

I have tried

```
grep -r 'John' myfile
```

Comment: Could you please add some examples..

Comment: Hi, the grep command should normally work. It would help if you also write how it failed. 
And the `-r` option to grep is for recursive search in a directory tree. You don't need that here.

Comment: Please correct the indentations..there is a spce in `Deepak khan (son)` between name and `(son)` while in `Nirmal khan(son)` there is no space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`) :

```
grep -Po '.*(?=\(son\))' file.txt
```

- `(?=\(son\))` is the zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring that `(son)` follows after the match i.e. only (`-o`) the names followed by `(son)` will be shown on the output

Example :

```
$ cat file.txt 
Name                   Age
Ashok Kumar(father)    32
Deepak khan(son)      19
Nirmal khan(son)       21

$ grep -Po '.*(?=\(son\))' file.txt 
Deepak khan
Nirmal khan
```

Comment: thanks, and how to get sum of their ages as well ? of all such occurrences?

Comment: @Aquarius24 you can't do that using `grep`, that would require a different tool and approach..please ask it as a new question..